# GDAL only reads one hole from Polygon in KML depending on wrapping of innerBoundaryIs

Tags: gdal, r, kml, sf

I have a KML file that contains a polygon with holes in it. It looks similar to this KML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Folder><name>polygon_with_holes</name>
    <Placemark>
        <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
        <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -95,45 -95.0,45.007 -94.99,45.007 -94.99,45.0 -95,45
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
            <innerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -94.999,45.003 -94.999,45.005 -94.997,45.005 -94.997,45.003 -94.999,45.003
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -94.996,45.001 -94.996,45.003 -94.994,45.003 -94.994,45.001 -94.996,45.001
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -94.993,45.004 -94.993,45.006 -94.991,45.006 -94.991,45.004 -94.993,45.004
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </innerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

This KML renders fine within Google Earth:

[image: google earth]

However, when I read this KML into R using `st_read` from the **sf** package, only the first hole gets read in:

```
> polygon1 <- st_read(dsn = '/path/to/file.kml', layer = 'polygon_with_holes')
> st_geometry(polygon1)[[1]]
# POLYGON ((-95 45, -95 45.007, -94.99 45.007, -94.99 45, -95 45), (-94.999 45.003, -94.999 45.005, -94.997 45.005, -94.997 45.003, -94.999 45.003))
> plot(st_geometry(polygon1), col = 'red')
```

[image: polygon1]

Note that the same behavior occurs with `readOGR` from the **sp** package, which leads me to believe this behavior is specific to GDAL. I've determined that wrapping each inner `LinearRing` with `innerBoundaryIs` tags solves the problem. In other words, the following KML is properly parsed by GDAL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Document id="root_doc">
<Folder><name>polygon_with_holes</name>
    <Placemark>
        <Style><LineStyle><color>ff0000ff</color></LineStyle><PolyStyle><fill>0</fill></PolyStyle></Style>
        <Polygon>
            <outerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -95,45 -95.0,45.007 -94.99,45.007 -94.99,45.0 -95,45
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </outerBoundaryIs>
            <innerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -94.999,45.003 -94.999,45.005 -94.997,45.005 -94.997,45.003 -94.999,45.003
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </innerBoundaryIs>
            <innerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -94.996,45.001 -94.996,45.003 -94.994,45.003 -94.994,45.001 -94.996,45.001
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </innerBoundaryIs>
            <innerBoundaryIs>
                <LinearRing>
                    <coordinates>
                        -94.993,45.004 -94.993,45.006 -94.991,45.006 -94.991,45.004 -94.993,45.004
                    </coordinates>
                </LinearRing>
            </innerBoundaryIs>
        </Polygon>
    </Placemark>
</Folder>
</Document></kml>
```

When this new KML is read into R:

```
> polygon2 <- st_read(dsn = '/path/to/newfile.kml', layer = 'polygon_with_holes')
> st_geometry(polygon2)[[1]]
# POLYGON ((-95 45, -95 45.007, -94.99 45.007, -94.99 45, -95 45), (-94.999 45.003, -94.999 45.005, -94.997 45.005, -94.997 45.003, -94.999 45.003), (-94.996 45.001, -94.996 45.003, -94.994 45.003, -94.994 45.001, -94.996 45.001), (-94.993 45.004, -94.993 45.006, -94.991 45.006, -94.991 45.004, -94.993 45.004))
> plot(st_geometry(polygon2), col = 'red')
```

[image: polygon2]

Unfortunately, the original offending file is part of an automated process, so fixing that file (and others like it) by hand is not a feasible option. So my questions are twofold:

- Is this the expected behavior of GDAL when parsing KML polygons with holes?
- Is there a GDAL option that can be invoked so that the original KML file is correctly parsed? (Preferrably something that can be passed in via the `options` argument to `st_read`.)

Comment: I believe that you should fix the automatic process. From https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#innerboundaryis I can read `<innerBoundaryIs>
    Contains a <LinearRing> element. A Polygon can contain multiple <innerBoundaryIs> elements, which create multiple cut-outs inside the Polygon.` Unfortunately the specification is not very exact about inner boundaries and linearrings.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037297/googlemaps-api-2-displays-only-1-innerboundary-linearring

Comment: Perhaps I should elaborate. Many parts of the process are automated, but I think the source of the KML is typically a shapefile converted to KML within ArcGIS. Please don't ask me why we convert shapefiles to KML... :)

Comment: Contact your ESRI support and ask if they have a bug in their product. Or the bug can be in GDAL and LIBKML even the latter is the reference implementation by Google http://www.gdal.org/drv_libkml.html.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the part of the KML XSD that defines what an `innerBoundaryIs` can be:

```
<element name="innerBoundaryIs" type="kml:BoundaryType"/>
```

From http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.3/ogckml23.xsd

So its a `BoundaryType` which is this:

```
<complexType name="BoundaryType" final="#all">
<all>
<element ref="kml:LinearRing" minOccurs="0"/>
<element ref="kml:BoundarySimpleExtensionGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
<element ref="kml:BoundaryObjectExtensionGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</all>
<anyAttribute namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
</complexType>
```

The `<element ref="kml:LinearRing" minOccurs="0"/>` says how many `LinearRing` elements are allowed in a `BoundaryType`, and the default for `maxOccurs` is 1, so this element can have zero or one `LinearRing`.

You'll have to read the XML in using one of R's XML readers, and reform it with each `LinearRing` in its own `innerBoundaryIs` to make the XML you give.

I just created a new polygon layer in QGIS with one feature with three holes, saved it to a shapefile and then converted to KML using `ogr2ogr`, and it correctly wrapped each inner boundary. I would say its a bug in whatever is writing your KML files, they are not compliant to the published spec.

Answer (score 0):

I have just encountered the same issue with a KML file, and have resolved it as per @Spacedman's answer by wrapping each hole `LinearRing` in `innerBoundaryIs` tags using three REGEX substitutions in Notepad++. This approach assumes that the external ring is already correctly tagged with `outerBoundaryIs`:

1. Remove newlines and indentation to allow the lookbehind in step 2 to work:

Search for: `\t+|\R+`

Replace with: *nothing*

2. Find all instances of `<LinearRing>` without a preceding `<innerBoundaryIs>` or `<outerBoundaryIs>` tag:

Search for: `(?<!BoundaryIs>)<LinearRing>`

Replace with: `<innerBoundaryIs><LinearRing>`

3. Find all instances of `<\LinearRing>` without a succeeding `<\innerBoundaryIs>` or `<\outerBoundaryIs>` tag:

Search for: `<\/LinearRing>(?!<\/.{5}BoundaryIs>)`

Replace with: `<\/LinearRing><\/innerBoundaryIs>`

The resulting file correctly loads in QGIS (using GDAL). Interestingly loading the modified KML file into Google Earth Pro and then saving it out results in the extra `innerBoundaryIs` tags being dropped again.